# Obtaining form data from within controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to obtain form data from the Angular controller without success.

**HTML**:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="entityName" ng-model="ent.Name">
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="this.blur()" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); saveData()">Save</button>
</form>`
```

**JS Controller**:

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
console.log($scope.ent.Name);
}
```

I receive error: **`Error: $scope.ent is undefined`**

Comment: I've added your code to code blocks instead of the `` and `<br>` that you used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always give form a `name` if you want angular validation to work. Shouldn't use `onclick` in angular app (asking for headaches and creating testing problems) `ng-clcik` will automatically prevent default so you don't need to add that yourself.

You probably haven't set up an object in scope for `ent`. If your `ng-model` values didn't have a dot in them you wouldn't need to register anything in scope for `ng-model` to work automatically creating a scope property

```
$scope.ent={};
```

This will be object that your `ng-model` properties will bind to. Will need to see more code if this isn't the issue

Comment: I added a `name` to my form, removed `ent.` from the `ng-model` and now the console outputs `undefined`.

Comment: create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle so can see more code. If you remove `ent.` from `ng-model` now should be able to log `$scope.Name`

Comment: Here is one http://plnkr.co/edit/dy01uwuj4ZkmQE2paPpT?p=preview that shows what charlietfl explained. I would recommend to always use a .(dot) in ng-model (reason: prototypicall inheritance)

Comment: agree with @bekite about keeping the dot, is safest angular practice to add them even when only using one property

Comment: @bekite - I played with the plunker code you provided and got mine to work. I was declaring `$scope.ent={};` in the wrong spot. Thanks everyone.